# Can two mobile phones accurately sense the distance between themselves?

Tags: sensor, wifi, gps, cellphone

This question is inspired from covid19 and current attempts to produce a contact tracing app for a mobile phone.

Can two mobile phones accurately (+- 1 m over a range 0-100 meters) sense the distance between themselves?

There are a number of ways phones can detect 'closeness'. If they're both connected to the same cell then they're probably within a few hundred meters of one another. Many mobile phones have built in GPS which can (on a good day) give a precision of +- 30 meters. However, most contact-tracing apps rely on blue-tooth, which given a class 1 device can have a range of 100m. As far as I know the current apps rely on simple binary detection - within range, or not within range. This is better than nothing, but isn't there any way of actually measuring distance between devices? (assuming 'standard' mobile phone hardware)

We're currently advised to maintain social distancing of 2 meters, so a contact-tracing app that can be triggered by being 100 meters of someone else is probably being over cautious. What's needed (IMHO) is an app that can determine risk based on accurate distance. i.e. within (say) 5m is a high risk. 5-15 m medium risk and 15-50 meters low risk.

Part 2 of my question is if phones can't accurately measure distance between themselves, is there an affordable and practical technology that could be applied (maybe some extra bit of hardware that could be plugged into a phone) to give better results?

Comment: Obviously they don't trigger on a 100 meter distance, because if they did, the whole city would be quarantined.

Comment: I think you can forget this idea. There were many questions on the topic six months ago. Some thought that the SSID would indicate range. It doesn't. It indicates signal quality which will deteriorate with distance but also with the number of Bluetooth (not "blue-tooth") collisions, reflections, etc. They also all fail when a false positive is given between two people either side of a wall. This, however, hasn't stopped government sponsored applications to do just what you are describing.

Comment: The Apple/Google system does indeed use "are these two phones within Bluetooth range of each other for a period of time", which approximates to "are in the same room". Realistically the range is more like 10m than 100m.

Comment: (Indoor location/distance sensing cheaply to any kind of reasonable accuracy is a surprisingly unsolved problem!)

Comment: RSSI based BLE proximity is hardly a new thing, the possibility and limitations are well know. 2 meters is no more a magic number in biology than it is in radio. Apart from the occasional phone model with a poor idea of its own receive sensitivity, the major technical issue is the intervening wall.  Privacy is obviously a concern, though the joint proposal goes to a substantial effort to honor that - many health authorities felt it did not propose to collect *enough* data as it specifically did not include the geolocation of the encounter.  The main issue is that this is **off topic**

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a question as this is exactly what Apple & Google's joint contact tracing feature is based on. You could question 'how' but there's plenty of info available. https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2020/04/challenge-proximity-apps-covid-19-contact-tracing for example.

Answer (score 1):

Given the wavelength of 0.12 meters at 2.4GHz, you would think something might be possible.

There is ambiguity in using the wavelength. And implanting a this_is_now marker into the narrow_band carriers is IMHO the problem, along with multipathing.

I recall work aimed at using the ramp_up of the digital_packet bits, because that provides a very prominent time signature, with of course 1/2.4GHZ = 0.4 nanosecond per cycle or 0.1 nanosecond per 1/4 cycle, **IF** the associated electronics can capture the ramping signature despite input_bandpass filtering between the antenna and the LNA (and down_mixers and IF amplifers with restricted bandwidth) into the Quantizer/ADC.

Comment: It actually just uses RSSI